# Block PHTML not Loading

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, controllers

I am following the 'Fundamentals of Magento 2' course and, I have to say, I am getting really frustrated with the example code being wrong on every exercise!

I am trying to set a template for a custom block within a controller. My folder structure is:

```
- /app/code/Training/Rendering/
    -- Block/Template.php
    -- Controller/Block/Template.php
    -- view/frontend/template.phtml
```

The routes are working fine as I can print output on the page from the controller. The files mentioned above (in order) contain the following:

**/app/code/Training/Rendering/Block/Template.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Training\Rendering\Block;


/**
 * Custom template block
 *
 * @package Training\Rendering\Block
 */
class Template extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

**app/code/Training/Rendering/Controller/Block/Template.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Training\Rendering\Controller\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

/**
 * Template Action Class
 * URL: testblock/Block/Template
 *
 * @package Training\Rendering\Controller\Block
 */
class Template extends Action
{

    /**
     * Execute Dispatch
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Training\Rendering\Block\Template');
        $block->setTemplate('template.phtml');
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody($block->toHtml());
    }
}
```

**app/code/Training/Rendering/view/frontend/template.phtml:**

```
<p>Hello from custom block template!</p>
```

I have tried changing the controller code to

`..->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template');` to test but no joy!

The problem is that the template (phtml) is not being loaded.

The code is exactly the same as the exercise (I tried copying and pasting from the PDF!).

I do understand that this will be handled with XML in the future, but in the interest of getting passed this exercise, I just need it to work like this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: which error are display?

Comment: @Rakesh There are no errors. Blank screen. If I echo text from the `execute` function, it is displayed. I just can't get the contents of `template.phtml` to load into the block

Comment: Are you want to get content of template file, have you check your execute method is called?

Comment: @Rakesh `execute` method is definitely called. As I just said, I can echo text from the method and the text is displayed on the screen under the correct URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your view template file directory is wrong, You had missing **templates** folder in your path,

**app/code/Training/Rendering/view/frontend/templates/template.phtml:**

```
<p>Hello from custom block template!</p>
```

call execute function with below code,
now call template like below,

**$block->setTemplate('Training_Rendering::template.phtml');**

```
 public function execute()
        {
            $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Training\Rendering\Block\Template');
            $block->setTemplate('Training_Rendering::template.phtml');
            $this->getResponse()->appendBody($block->toHtml());
        }
```

Comment: Wow. This exercise guide is really messed up! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can close this question after mark as accepted.

Comment: Just had to wait before I could mark as answered. Done now.

Comment: Just one question, Rakesh: How did you know to set the template this way? I would assume it to be in the Magento docs but I can't find it

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, the javascript written in this file not working, how can we print the phtml file js code in browser console

Answer (score -2):

Create object of `PageFactory` in controller and return it.

**example:-**

```
return $this->pageFactory->create();
```